# In PHP can you extend a class to the same name?

Tags: php, class, extends

I'm trying to find out weather I can do this or not. I have a class called Template. and I want to extend that classes functionality in another file, but I don't want to change the name.

Do I declare it as

```
class template extends template
{
   // code here
   function foo()
   {

   }
}
```

or do I just declare it like this?

```
class template
{
   // write function
   function foo()
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You might want to check out [classkit](http://www.php.net/classkit)

Comment: In this case coding features change, it allow to do that, but not right & easy way. like to upgrade a software should be directly via class.

Comment: Link goes to non existent page

Answer (score 37):

Only if the parent class is in another namespace.

```
use SomeNamespace\Template as BaseTemplate;

class Template extends BaseTemplate 
{
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use a method/property of the original class you can extend it but you must use a different name, otherwise you'll get an error about redeclaring the class.

Basically:

```
class template {}

/* both fail with "cannot redeclare class template */

class template extends template {}

class template {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can not. I would suggest you do the following:

```
class Template extends TemplateBase
{
    // code
}
```

read more at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php